# Accelerometer movement limit according to screen size

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I am using this code:

```
void Update()
{
    accel = Input.acceleration.x;
    transform.Translate (0, 0, accel);
    transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x,-6.9f, 6.9f), -4.96f, 18.3f);
}
```

It makes my gameObject move the way I want it BUT the problem is that when I put the app on my phone, `(-6.9)` and `(6.9)` are not the "ends" of my screen. And I cannot figure out how to change those values according to every screen size?

Comment: Use `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` and try to avoid hardcoding variables as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for replaying. Can you explain how to use screen.width and height?

Comment: I would try to, but I don't have enough information to help you with it in your context. Can you post an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well imagine a game in which you have objects falling and you have to collect them in by tilting the device in order to move another gameObject( a basket for example). But i have to limit the movement so that the "basket" doesn't go out of the screen. That is why I added those hardcoded variables but now when i play it on my phone the screen is larger and the "basket" doesnt go to end of the screen.So i need those variables ot change for every screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a bit of a longer answer, so please bear with me here.

Note that this post is assuming that you are using an *orthographic* camera - the formula used won't work for perspective cameras.

As far as I can understand your desire is to keep your object inside of the screen boundaries. Screen boundaries in Unity are determined by a combination of camera size and screen size.

```
float height = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;
```

A camera's orthographic size determines the half of the screen's size in *world units*. Multiplying this value results in the amount of world units between the top and bottom of the screen.

To get the width from this value, we take the value and multiplying it by the screen's width divided by the screen's height.

```
float width = height * Screen.width / Screen.height;
```

Now we have the dimensions of our screen, but we still need to keep the object inside those bounds.

First, we create an instance of the type [`Bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html), which we will use to determine the maximum and minimum values for the position.

```
Bounds bounds = new Bounds (Vector3.zero, new Vector3(width, height, 0));
```

Note that we used `Vector3.zero` since the center of our bounds instance should be the world's center. This is the center of the area that your object should be able to move inside.

Lastly, we clamp the object's position values, according to our resulting bounds' properties.

```
Vector3 clampedPosition = transform.position;
clampedPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPosition.x, bounds.min.x, bounds.max.x);
transform.position = clampedPosition;
```

This should ensure that your object will never leave the screen's side boundaries!

Comment: So thanks for the explanation but now unity gives me errors for bounds.min.x and bounds.max.x :'Assets/scripts/controller.cs(31,54): error CS0103: The name `bounds' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: @TodorValkov You have to save the variable `bounds` somewhere obviously, maybe in a private variable in your controller script.

Comment: @TodorValkov You are welcome! Be sure to accept this answer, if it helped you. If you need any more help, don't hesitate to ask.